# What do you have on your (physical) desk?

Tags: hardware

I'm settling in a new office and except the obvious (PC, screen, mouse, keyboard) and the can't-work-without earphones, tissue box, Philips screwdriver and stack (overflow?) of papers my table looks poor, empty and not functional.

**Which tools of the trade do you keep in your desk? What proves useful to keep within an arm's reach?**

Answer (score 5):

An external hard drive dock always comes along handy.  Such as [this one](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/usb-gadgets/a7ea/).

Comment: I read your question perhaps 5 times each time I came back to this question, and only now do I understand you said DOCK not CLOCK: http://www.google.com/search?q=hard%20drive%20clock - Because external hard drive clocks are the bomb.

Comment: Haha, I think I might add a hard drive clock to my desk also.  They look pretty awesome :P

Answer (score 3):

I always keep one of my own business cards on my desk because I can never seem to remember my own work phone number when I'm on the phone with someone who needs it.

--
bmb

Comment: Yep or the company main line or fax number either

Answer (score 3):

- My coffee mug
- My laptop on a stand with 2nd monitor
- Baseline desktop machine for testing
- Half a library of IT & programming language reference books
- My coffee mug
- Power strip so I don't have to crawl under my desk to plug all my crap in
- Jug o' Purell hand-sanitizer for fighting off the crud from all of the keyboards in our building that have not been cleaned for a decade
- My coffee mug
- Compressed air.  Never know when you need to blow out a machine or play ping-pong ball hockey
- A small whiteboard with those awesome smelling markers
- Awesome smelling whiteboard cleaner
- My coffee mug
- Screen wipes for those SCHMOES that can't keep their stinkin' fingers off of my monitor when they're showing me something
- Dust bunnies that would choke a cat (in stark contrast to the jug o' Purell)
- Dilbert books
- My coffee mug
- Calvin and Hobbes books
- Fox Trot books
- A Bible
- Oh yeah, and lots and lots of pictures of my wife and kids

And my coffee mug

Answer (score 2):

I have the cables necessary to setup and work on a second PC ... monitor, keyboard and mouse, power cable plugged in, ethernet cable plugged in.  That way, when I am in a hurry to fix a problem I can plug the PC and go.

Answer (score 2):

One sixth of my 3'x8' desk surface is occupied by a folded blanket that is usually occupied by a big, fat, white cat.  There's something incredibly calming about this animal who has no cares except eating and getting his ears scratched.  Very calming.

Comment: As long as the hairballs stay off your desk, your golden

Answer (score 2):

Those things should be easely reache :

- USB Port by an extension cable laying on the desk
- ESata Port by an extension once again, this is more and more current these days
- A good mouse pad with wrist rest padded
- Monitor stand (allsop make a good one) to elevate the monitor so you neck is straight
- A coffe cup and a coffee brewer can also be a good ideas!

Comment: Power to the coffee cup

Answer (score 2):

Books like the below.  Aside from my computer I find that nothing is as helpful has having books to be able grab and open.  My books of course have lots of the Post-It Flags marking important sections.  When the network is down, firing up Google or [Safari](http://my.safaribooksonline.com) isn't an option, and I am not able to remember everything.

- [TCP/IP Network Administration](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565923225/)
- [Network Troubleshooting Tools](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001865/)
- [Learning the bash Shell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009656/)
- And so on...

Comment: I'd say the networking books WOULD be important when the network is down <G>.  Then again it's also a good reason to have a cellular modem

Answer (score 0):

I also have:

- mousepad
- pen
- PostITs
- Thermoisolated tea cup

Answer (score 0):

[moleskine notebook](http://www.moleskineus.com/)

[Ball of whacks](http://www.creativewhack.com/)

pencils, keyboard and mouse

...and sometimes m&ms.

Answer (score 0):

Pumpkin seeds, peanuts, sunflower seeds, whichever, must have the the 1500 hour snack on hand to keep my head from diving into my keyboard

Comment: Didn't you know?  "Typing with your face" is the new "in thing"